# Modifying one object in list modifies all objects in list

Tags: python, list, object, vector

I am trying to make a list of coordinates directly adjacent to any given point in a 3d grid.
For example, when given a vector {3,3,3}, the function should return the following list:

```
[{4,3,3},{2,3,3},{3,4,3},{3,2,3},{3,3,4},{3,3,2}]
```

(The values in curly braces are vector objects, not lists.)
Here is my code:

```
def touchingBlocks(sourceBlock):
    touching = []
    for t in range(6):
        touching.append(sourceBlock)
    touching[0].x += 1
    touching[1].x -= 1
    touching[2].y += 1
    touching[3].y -= 1
    touching[4].z += 1
    touching[5].z -= 1
    return touching
```

(sourceBlock is a vector object.)

When I try to modify any one of the objects in the list though, it modifies every object. For example, after the touching[0].x += 1 command, I would expect touching to be equal to:

```
[{4,3,3},{3,3,3},{3,3,3},{3,3,3},{3,3,3},{3,3,3}]
```

(Assuming we gave the function the vector {3,3,3})
Instead, the 'x' value of every object got changed, instead of only the first. By the end of the function, this error results in simply returning a list of six copies of the original vector.

I think this might be because the objects in the list are just pointers to the same version of sourceBlock, though I am not sure. Can you confirm if I am right and how to fix this?

Also, here is the link to the vector object, in case you need to look in there:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpuo6473z225la7/vec3.py

Comment: Try replacing `touching.append(sourceBlock)` with `touching.append(copy(sourceBlock))`.

Comment: You look like you're coming from a language where assignment creates copies. [This](http://rg03.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/semantics-of-python-variable-names-from-a-c-perspective/) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def touchingBlocks(sourceBlock):
    touching = []
    for t in range(6):
        touching.append(sourceBlock)  # Here is your error
    touching[0].x += 1
    touching[1].x -= 1
    touching[2].y += 1
    touching[3].y -= 1
    touching[4].z += 1
    touching[5].z -= 1
    return touching
```

You are adding the same object 6 times. Everytime you edit one object, you edit
them all. You should create copies of your obect using [copy.depcopy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)
(deepcopy will copy the nested objects as well, not just their reference)

```
import copy
[...code...]
touching.append(copy.deepcopy(sourceBlock))
```